# MatLab dot product of complex valued vectors not working correctly

Tags: matlab, math, complex-numbers, dot-product

```
>> a = [a1 a2]

a =

   2.0000 + 0.0000i  -1.0000 + 1.7321i

>> b = [b1 b2]

b =

   2.0000 + 0.0000i  -1.0000 - 1.7321i

>> dot(a,b)

ans =

   2.0000 + 3.4641i

>> a1*b1+a2*b2

ans =

     8
```

Why am I getting such a weird value for taking the dot product of two complex valued vectors? I am pretty sure the answer should be 8, but I still get 2.0000 + 3.4641i as shown above. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation,

> dot(A,B) is the same as A'*B.

so, if you try:

```
a = [2.0000 + 0.0000i  -1.0000 + 1.7321i]
b = [2.0000 + 0.0000i  -1.0000 - 1.7321i]
dot(conj(a),b)
```

You'll get:

```
>> dot(conj(a),b)

ans =

    8.0002
```

Comment: But doesnt the documentation say that is only true if they are column vectors?

Comment: Also, i think the a' indicates the transpose of a, as opposed to its conjugate.

Comment: Sorry, it looks it takes the tranpose AND conjugate. Sorry about that. Thanks for the response

Comment: As is correct and expected for a scalar product of a complex vector space. See hermitean scalar product or sesquilinear bilinear form.